# Refresh page before downloading content?

Tags: javascript, html, time, async-await

So I have been working on an image sharing site, similar to [imgBB](https://imgbb.com/). And I am having trouble with the downloading feature in my website! I mostly code the backend of websites so I only know so much about frontend. I am trying to download an image using the following code:

```js
//Javascript
document.getElementById('downloadImage').src = 'images/image.png';
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<!--The Download() function will be explained in a bit.-->
<button onclick="Download()" id="downloadImage">Download Image</button>
```

And I need to refresh the page *before* the download occurs. I tried the following code with no luck.

```js
function Download() {
  window.location.reload();
    document.getElementById('downloadImage').src = 'images/image.png'
};
//The HTML page is the same.
```

I have also tried this with `async/await` functions with no luck either.

## The point

Make the page refresh before downloading content.

So can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why must you reload before download?

Comment: Just use <a href='images/image.png' download='image.png'>Download</a> instead of your button